# Stop opening files when drag and drop in explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I drag and drop any file to Visual Studio Code's explorer, it automatically opens this file in the editor. **Are there any settings to turn off this behavior?**

Usually, I work with large and heavy CSV, JSON, etc., so when these files open it can really slow down my computer, also because some extensions like text highlighting automatically try to parse the text, but until it realizes that it is too much content to do his job and shows a warning that it won't continue because of performance issues, it has already slowed down my computer.

Of course, I can just close fast enough the file before this happens, but sometimes the problem still occurs (and anyway it should be possible to disable this feature).

Answer (score 1):

I cloned a source of `vscode` to find solution. This is what I found in the source, when dragging multiple files, nothing will open:

**vscode/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/views/explorerViewer.ts**:

```
// if we only add one file, just open it directly
if (resourceFileEdits.length === 1) {
  const item = this.explorerService.findClosest(resourceFileEdits[0].newResource!);
  if (item && !item.isDirectory) {
    this.editorService.openEditor({ resource: item.resource, options: { pinned: true } });
  }
}
```

this code placed in:

```
 private async addResources(target: ExplorerItem, resources: URI[], token: CancellationToken): Promise<void> {
```

and called from `handleExternalDrop` function.

```
private async handleExternalDrop(target: ExplorerItem, originalEvent: DragEvent, token: CancellationToken): Promise<void> {
```

Of course, this is not a solution if there is only one file.

And you probably need to create
a [4.6k + 1 issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)

Comment: It's not that :( I still want to drag and drop the files, I just don't want them to automatically open. This setting won't let me drag and drop at all

Comment: I think there isn't that option.

Comment: I thought so... I will open an issue on their GitHub, thanks!

Comment: I think that they will refuse to implement it and suggest to use mv command instead drag. But Good Luck!

Comment: Do you have a link to this github issue if you've opened one? I'd like to do the same but don't want to dupe it and couldn't find it through search.

Comment: No I don't have

Comment: @James I haven't opened it yet! I've been busy (and lazy) to do it, but if you do I will show up there to give more visibility to the problem

Comment: @EduardoCôrtes I updated my answer, I hope it's better than it was.

Comment: Any answer staring I cloned the source code to have a look deserves up votes in my book

Comment: vscode issues: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168809